# Gap between quotation marks with csquotes, for example with mathpazo

Tags: csquotes, quotation, mathpazo

It has been my belief that csquotes takes care of the need to have some whitespace between consecutive opening or closing quotation marks, so you don't have to add a `\thinspace` at the right place as recommended in the TeXbook. At least this looks good both with or without the line with mathpazo:

```
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\begin{document}
\enquote{aaa \enquote{bbb}}

\enquote{\enquote{aaa} bbb}

\end{document}
```

With the mathpazo line it looks like this:

[image]

But with `\usepackage[osf]{mathpazo}` instead it turns out like this:

[image]

So almost even spaced out which makes it unclear. Is this a bug/misfeature in that font? How can I adjust it?

Answer (score 4):

The `mathpazo` package is quite old. If having a Palatino clone text and math font for your document is your "thing", you may be better off employing the `newpxtext` and `newpxmath` packages -- whether or not your document features nested `\enquote` directives.

[image]

Adding or omitting the `osf` option makes no difference.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[osf]{newpxtext}
\usepackage{newpxmath}
\usepackage[english=american]{csquotes}
\begin{document}

\enquote{aaa \enquote{bbb}}

\enquote{\enquote{aaa} bbb}

\end{document}
```

Comment: And if you can use a Unicode engine like LuaTeX or XeTeX, you can use the desktop version of Palatino, or the clones Pagella or Domitian.